# JpaRepository - delete method - inform that entity does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

During **delete** operation, can a **JpaRepository** inform me, that **entity** I want to remove **does not exists**?

I know that delete methods doesn't returns **boolean** value, and also doesn't throws **Exceptions**.

**I also know that I can just simply do exists() or findOne() and then perform delete, but I'm just curious.**

**Is there any way to force this?**

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.1.
Sample code below:

```
public HttpStatus deleteEventByTitle(String eventTitle) {
    try {
        eventRepository.deleteByTitle(eventTitle);
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) { // just showing what I want to do
        return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
    }
    return HttpStatus.OK;
}


public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, Long> {

    void deleteByTitle(String title);

}
```

Comment: Change void to int, thus having `int deleteByTitle(String title);`. This will make returning the affected rows. Therefore if you have return > 0 then something was deleted. If you want an additional method like `deleteByTitleOrThrow(String title)` then you can create an ...Impl class and an additional interface meant to extend the behavior and add that method to it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Starting from Spring Data JPA (>=1.7.x), we can use the [derived](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-delete#derived-delete) `delete` or `remove` query. It can return the number of entities deleted or what all entities are deleted.

Using it we can update our code as:

```
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, Long> {
    long deleteByTitle(String title);
}
```

and we can throw an exception if the entity doesn't exist.

```
public HttpStatus deleteEventByTitle(String eventTitle) {
    long numOfEntriesDeleted = eventRepository.deleteByTitle(eventTitle);
    if(numOfEntriesDeleted != 1){
       return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
    }
    return HttpStatus.OK;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the spec this is not possible and I am not aware of a functionality like this.

I know that when working with Cassandra and Datastax you can check `wasApplied()`.

The only way around would be to implement your own `deleteOrThrowException`-method and throw an exception in case you didn't find the entity.

In order to achieve this you could add a

```
@Query("select count(event)>0 from Event e where eventTitle := eventTitle")
public boolean existsByTitle(String eventTitle);
```

Comment: Hm. So i think the best way will be to write @Query("..") Boolean existsByTitle, because Spring Data does not support existsByAttribute.

Comment: Updated with example.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if it exists before deleting it:

```
// Check if the ID is available
if (deviceRepository.existsById(id)) {
    deviceRepository.deleteById(id);
    //returnObject.setMessage("Deleted successfully !!");

} else {
    //returnObject.setMessage("The ID is not found");
}
```

Comment: This is not safe in a multithreaded environment since between the db querying and the delete another query could've deleted the entity.